# How to listen for the clipboard "owner-change" event in gtk-rs?

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk-rs

I am writing a application based on `gtk::Clipboard` in using the gtk-rs crate. I have already initialized a `Clipboard` like this:

```
let clipboard = gtk::Clipboard::get(&gdk::SELECTION_PRIMARY);
```

It is able to print the selected text by using `clipboard.wait_for_text()` in loop.

However, I only need the text when the selection changes. How can I connect a handling function to the `owner-change` event emitted from `clipboard`?

In Python, it could be implemented like [this](https://github.com/bianjp/popup-dict/blob/dbf9121aa63d65095bd848a582595e1b03327418/popupdict/ui/popup.py#L35)

```py
clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY)
clipboard.connect("owner-change", foo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clipboard.rs` [contains the following comment](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk/blob/4942479eebc69f75808a720a514d5b78700642c8/src/auto/clipboard.rs#L229-L231):

```rust
//pub fn connect_owner_change<Unsupported or ignored types>(&self, f: F) -> SignalHandlerId {
//    Ignored event: Gdk.EventOwnerChange
//}
```

so this feature is likely not (yet) supported.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have found this too. Is there any solutions else?